# VueJS Prop Validation Using Typescript Interface Type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following VueJS component (typescript, vue-property-decorator):

```
import {PropType} from 'vue';
import {Component, Vue, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import {buildRouteLink, Route} from 'my-config';

@Component
export default class Report extends Vue {
  // I've also tried Object as () => Route, which also doesn't work
  @Prop({type: Object as PropType<Route>, required: true})
  private route!: Route;
  private url: string = '';
  mounted() {
    this.url = buildRouteLink(this.route);
  }
}
```

The issue is, if I mount the component like:

```
<report :route="route"/>
```

And pass the `route` property as a type that doesn't conform to the `Route` interface ( eg: `{foo: true}` ), I get no runtime validation error, only an error in `buildRouteLink()`, which expects `Route` fields to exist.

The `Route` interface is simple:

```
interface Route {
  app: string;
  route: string;
}
```

- **`typescript` version**: 3.2.4
- **`vue` version**: 2.6.10
- **`vue-property-decorator` version**: 7.3.0

Comment: I was following this article, which goes into a description of what's happening - https://frontendsociety.com/using-a-typescript-interfaces-and-types-as-a-prop-type-in-vuejs-508ab3f83480

Comment: So this is some Vue functionality that isn't working as expected? I'll have to defer to someone who knows about Vue, then.  Good luck!

Comment: @Blaskovicz Assuming `buildRouteLink`'s argument is typed with `Route`, there should still be a compile time error when you try to pass it something that isn't `Route`. I wasn't able to reproduce this error using the latest Vue CLI generated TypeScript project.